# Import errors using sass files and pug with vue-cli 3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to set up a Vue project using vue-cli 3.x, typescript, pug and .sass files.

I also want to import a couple files globally so that they are available in all my components (I [followed this guide](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/))

**main.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import '@/sass/main.sass'
```

**main.sass**

```
@import partials/variables
@import ../../node_modules/globl.css/main
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: `
                    @import "@/sass/partials/_variables.sass";
                    @import "./node_modules/globl.css/partials/_mixins.sass";
                `
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Navbar component giving me errors**

```
<template lang="pug">
.navbar Navbar
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({})
</script>

<style lang="sass">
.navbar 
    color: red
</style>
```

**Error log**

[image]

I noticed that if I remove the sass from the component and convert it to scss the error goes away...

The other issue, in the main.sass file, is still a mystery to me..

Comment: @QuentinVeron sass-loader is throwing the error in the screenshot?

Comment: Is your `main.sass`file correctly formatted as `sass`, the error message state that it's containing brackets ?

Comment: Yeah. And it shouldn’t contain brackets since it’s SASS and not scss

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Did you ever solve this?